# Treeview With Nested Checkbox Nodes Selection

Tags: javascript, css, checkbox, treeview, nested

So I want to have a treeview with nested checkbox nodes selection, and I've found a nice example to suit my need [here](http://experiments.wemakesites.net/css3-treeview-with-multiple-node-selection.html).

However, I am unable to duplicate the code to my own site or jsfiddle -- I've created everything required in this fiddle [jsfiddle.net/rkv95zax/](http://jsfiddle.net/rkv95zax/), but it is not working as the original site. I.e., the nested selection is not there. What I am missing? Thanks.

UPDATE: OK. I've figured it out, in http://jsfiddle.net/rkv95zax/1/. Full code enclosed below.

Now could someone show me how to walk this treenode and showing only selected leaf nodes please?

```
CSS:

/*
 * Imageless CSS3 Treeview with Checkbox Support
 * @namespace window.AcidJs
 * @class CSS3Treeview
 * @version 3.0
 * @author Martin Ivanov
 * @url developer website: http://wemakesites.net/
 * @url developer twitter: https://twitter.com/#!/wemakesitesnet
 * @url developer blog http://acidmartin.wordpress.com/
 **/

/*
 * Do you like this solution? Please, donate:
 * https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=QFUHPWJB2JDBS
 **/

.acidjs-css3-treeview,
.acidjs-css3-treeview *
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.acidjs-css3-treeview label[for]::before,
.acidjs-css3-treeview label span::before
{
    content: "\25b6";
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
    color: #e74c3c;
    font-size: 8px;
    line-height: 13px;
}

.acidjs-css3-treeview li ul
{
    margin: 0 0 0 22px;
}

.acidjs-css3-treeview *
{
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.acidjs-css3-treeview
{
    font: normal 11px/16px "Segoe UI", Arial, Sans-serif;
}

.acidjs-css3-treeview li
{
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.acidjs-css3-treeview input[type="checkbox"]
{
    display: none;
}

.acidjs-css3-treeview label
{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.acidjs-css3-treeview label[for]::before
{
    -webkit-transform: translatex(-24px);
    -moz-transform: translatex(-24px);
    -ms-transform: translatex(-24px);
    -o-transform: translatex(-24px);
    transform: translatex(-24px);
}

.acidjs-css3-treeview label span::before
{
    -webkit-transform: translatex(16px);
    -moz-transform: translatex(16px);
    -ms-transform: translatex(16px);
    -o-transform: translatex(16px);
    transform: translatex(16px);
}

.acidjs-css3-treeview input[type="checkbox"][id]:checked ~ label[for]::before
{
    content: "\25bc";
}

.acidjs-css3-treeview input[type="checkbox"][id]:not(:checked) ~ ul
{
    display: none;
}

.acidjs-css3-treeview label:not([for])
{
    margin: 0 8px 0 0;
}

.acidjs-css3-treeview label span::before
{
    content: "";
    border: solid 1px #1375b3;
    color: #1375b3;
    opacity: .50;
}

.acidjs-css3-treeview label input:checked + span::before
{
    content: "\2714";
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25) inset;
    opacity: 1;
}

HTML: 

<h3>Demo</h3>

<p>Another version of the treeview without checkbox support is available on  
    <a href="css3-treeview.html" target="_blank">this page</a>.</p>

<div class="acidjs-css3-treeview">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="node-0" checked="checked" /><label><input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0">Libraries</label>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-0" checked="checked" /><label><input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-0">Documents</label>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-0-0" checked="checked" /><label><input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-0-0">My Documents</label>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-0-0-0" /><label><input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-0-0-0">Downloads</label>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-0-0-1" /><label><input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-0-0-1">Projects</label>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-1" /><label><input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-1">Music</label>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-1-0" /><label><input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-1-0">My Music</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-1-1" /><label><input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-1-1">Public Music</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-2" /><label><input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-2">Pictures</label>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-2-0" /><label><input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-2-0">My Pictures</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-2-1" /><label><input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-2-1">Public Pictures</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-3" checked="checked" /><label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-3">Video</label>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-3-0" /><label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-3-0">My Videos</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-3-1" /><label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-3-1">Public Videos</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

Javascript:

$(".acidjs-css3-treeview").delegate("label input:checkbox", "change", function() {
    var
        checkbox = $(this),
        nestedList = checkbox.parent().next().next(),
        selectNestedListCheckbox = nestedList.find("label:not([for]) input:checkbox");

    if(checkbox.is(":checked")) {
        return selectNestedListCheckbox.prop("checked", true);
    }
    selectNestedListCheckbox.prop("checked", false);
});
```

Comment: I was never able to put the link in op, http://jsfiddle.net/rkv95zax/, regardless how many times/ways I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, the site never mentioned jquery and the keyword "jquery" didn't show up in its html source either.

Now it works:

```
jsfiddle.net/rkv95zax/1/
```

UPDATE: I don't know if walking the above treenode is possible, but I've found this:

**Multiple Checkbox Select/Deselect - DEMO**
http://jsfiddle.net/jLx5z99q/